# Access to client local internet and vpn server local network

Tags: configuration, routing, openvpn

When I connect to openvpn, I want to be able to access the devices in the openvpn local network and use my local internet. But I can only access local internet and openvpn server machine. Can't access devices in local network of openvpn server. I couldn't find where the problem is.

***Server.conf:***

```
   local 13.131.31.36
   port 35984
   proto udp
   dev tun
   ca ca.crt
   cert server.crt
   key server.key
   dh dh.pem
   auth SHA512
   tls-crypt tc.key
   topology subnet
   server 13.131.32.0 255.255.255.0
   #push "redirect-gateway local"
   #push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
   push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
   push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
   ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
   keepalive 10 120
   data-ciphers AES-256-GCM:AES-256-CBC
   user nobody
   group nogroup
   persist-key
   persist-tun
   verb 3
   crl-verify crl.pem
   explicit-exit-notify
   auth-nocache
   push "route 13.131.31.0 255.255.255.0 13.131.32.1"
   push "route 13.131.30.0 255.255.255.0 13.131.32.1"
   push "client-to-client"
```

***client.ovpn:***

```
   client
   dev tun
   proto udp
   remote 13.131.31.36 12345
   resolv-retry infinite
   nobind
   persist-key
   persist-tun
   remote-cert-tls server
   auth SHA512
   cipher AES-256-CBC
   verb 3
   push "route 13.131.30.0 255.255.255.0 13.131.32.1"
   push "route 13.131.31.0 255.255.255.0 13.131.32.1"
```

***ip routing:***

```
   default via 13.131.31.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 13.131.31.36 metric 100
   default via 13.131.30.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 13.131.30.11 metric 600
   8.8.8.8 via 13.131.30.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 13.131.30.11 metric 600
   13.131.30.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 13.131.30.11 metric 600
   13.131.30.1 via 13.131.31.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 13.131.31.36 metric 100
   13.131.30.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 13.131.30.11 metric 600
   13.131.31.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 13.131.31.36 metric 100
   13.131.31.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 13.131.31.36 metric 100
   13.131.32.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 13.131.32.1
```

***Client.log***

```
    2023-08-22 14:19:09 DEPRECATED OPTION: --cipher set to 'AES-256-CBC' but missing in --data-ciphers (AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM). Future OpenVPN version will ignore --cipher for cipher negotiations. Add 'AES-256-CBC' to --data-ciphers or change --cipher 'AES-256-CBC' to --data-ciphers-fallback 'AES-256-CBC' to silence this warning.
    2023-08-22 14:19:09 OpenVPN 2.5.5 Windows-MSVC [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [PKCS11] [AEAD] built on Dec 15 2021
    2023-08-22 14:19:09 Windows version 10.0 (Windows 10 or greater) 64bit
    2023-08-22 14:19:09 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021, LZO 2.10
    2023-08-22 14:19:09 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
    2023-08-22 14:19:09 Need hold release from management interface, waiting...
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'log all on'
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'echo all on'
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'bytecount 5'
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold off'
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:12345
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 UDP link local: (not bound)
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:12345
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1692703150,WAIT,,,,,,
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1692703150,AUTH,,,,,,
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:12345, sid=4f0124e2 f953d9c4
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 VERIFY OK: depth=1, CN=Easy-RSA CA
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 VERIFY KU OK
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 Validating certificate extended key usage
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 ++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 VERIFY EKU OK
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=server
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 WARNING: 'link-mtu' is used inconsistently, local='link-mtu 1601', remote='link-mtu 1585'
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 WARNING: 'keysize' is used inconsistently, local='keysize 256', remote='keysize 128'
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 Control Channel: TLSv1.3, cipher TLSv1.3 TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, peer certificate: 2048 bit RSA, signature: RSA-SHA256
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 [server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:12345
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4,route 13.131.31.0 255.255.255.0 13.131.32.1,route 13.131.30.0 255.255.255.0 13.131.32.1,client-to-client,route-gateway 13.131.32.1,topology subnet,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 13.131.32.2 255.255.255.0,peer-id 1,cipher AES-256-GCM'
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 Options error: option 'client-to-client' cannot be used in this context ([PUSH-OPTIONS])
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 OPTIONS IMPORT: peer-id set
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 OPTIONS IMPORT: adjusting link_mtu to 1624
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 OPTIONS IMPORT: data channel crypto options modified
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 Data Channel: using negotiated cipher 'AES-256-GCM'
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 Outgoing Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 Incoming Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 interactive service msg_channel=1008
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 open_tun
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 tap-windows6 device [Yerel Ağ Bağlantısı] opened
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 TAP-Windows Driver Version 9.24 
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 Set TAP-Windows TUN subnet mode network/local/netmask = 13.131.32.0/13.131.32.2/255.255.255.0 [SUCCEEDED]
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 Notified TAP-Windows driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of 13.131.32.2/255.255.255.0 on interface {269323C2-CA34-4A09-A10B-3C465C1A9832} [DHCP-serv: 13.131.32.0, lease-time: 31536000]
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 Successful ARP Flush on interface [4] {269323C2-CA34-4A09-A10B-3C465C1A9832}
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1692703150,ASSIGN_IP,,13.131.32.2,,,,
    2023-08-22 14:19:10 IPv4 MTU set to 1500 on interface 4 using service
    2023-08-22 14:19:15 TEST ROUTES: 2/2 succeeded len=2 ret=1 a=0 u/d=up
    2023-08-22 14:19:15 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1692703155,ADD_ROUTES,,,,,,
    2023-08-22 14:19:15 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 13.131.31.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 13.131.32.1
    2023-08-22 14:19:15 Route addition via service succeeded
    2023-08-22 14:19:15 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 13.131.30.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 13.131.32.1
    2023-08-22 14:19:15 Route addition via service succeeded
    2023-08-22 14:19:15 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
    2023-08-22 14:19:15 Initialization Sequence Completed
    2023-08-22 14:19:15 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1692703155,CONNECTED,SUCCESS,13.131.32.2,XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX,12345,,
    2023-08-22 14:19:22 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe DELETE 13.131.31.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 13.131.32.1
    2023-08-22 14:19:22 Route deletion via service succeeded
    2023-08-22 14:19:22 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe DELETE 13.131.30.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 13.131.32.1
    2023-08-22 14:19:22 Route deletion via service succeeded
    2023-08-22 14:19:22 Closing TUN/TAP interface
    2023-08-22 14:19:22 TAP: DHCP address released
    2023-08-22 14:19:22 SIGTERM[hard,] received, process exiting
    2023-08-22 14:19:22 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1692703162,EXITING,SIGTERM,,,,,
    2023-08-22 14:30:45 DEPRECATED OPTION: --cipher set to 'AES-256-CBC' but missing in --data-ciphers (AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM). Future OpenVPN version will ignore --cipher for cipher negotiations. Add 'AES-256-CBC' to --data-ciphers or change --cipher 'AES-256-CBC' to --data-ciphers-fallback 'AES-256-CBC' to silence this warning.
    2023-08-22 14:30:45 OpenVPN 2.5.5 Windows-MSVC [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [PKCS11] [AEAD] built on Dec 15 2021
    2023-08-22 14:30:45 Windows version 10.0 (Windows 10 or greater) 64bit
    2023-08-22 14:30:45 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021, LZO 2.10
    2023-08-22 14:30:45 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
    2023-08-22 14:30:45 Need hold release from management interface, waiting...
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'log all on'
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'echo all on'
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'bytecount 5'
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold off'
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:12345
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 UDP link local: (not bound)
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:12345
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1692703846,WAIT,,,,,,
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1692703846,AUTH,,,,,,
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:12345, sid=f8e69e29 22426885
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 VERIFY OK: depth=1, CN=Easy-RSA CA
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 VERIFY KU OK
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 Validating certificate extended key usage
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 ++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 VERIFY EKU OK
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=server
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 WARNING: 'link-mtu' is used inconsistently, local='link-mtu 1601', remote='link-mtu 1585'
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 WARNING: 'keysize' is used inconsistently, local='keysize 256', remote='keysize 128'
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 Control Channel: TLSv1.3, cipher TLSv1.3 TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, peer certificate: 2048 bit RSA, signature: RSA-SHA256
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 [server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:12345
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4,route 13.131.31.0 255.255.255.0 13.131.32.1,route 13.131.30.0 255.255.255.0 13.131.32.1,client-to-client,route-gateway 13.131.32.1,topology subnet,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 13.131.32.2 255.255.255.0,peer-id 0,cipher AES-256-GCM'
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 Options error: option 'client-to-client' cannot be used in this context ([PUSH-OPTIONS])
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 OPTIONS IMPORT: peer-id set
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 OPTIONS IMPORT: adjusting link_mtu to 1624
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 OPTIONS IMPORT: data channel crypto options modified
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 Data Channel: using negotiated cipher 'AES-256-GCM'
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 Outgoing Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 Incoming Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 interactive service msg_channel=664
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 open_tun
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 tap-windows6 device [Yerel Ağ Bağlantısı] opened
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 TAP-Windows Driver Version 9.24 
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 Set TAP-Windows TUN subnet mode network/local/netmask = 13.131.32.0/13.131.32.2/255.255.255.0 [SUCCEEDED]
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 Notified TAP-Windows driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of 13.131.32.2/255.255.255.0 on interface {269323C2-CA34-4A09-A10B-3C465C1A9832} [DHCP-serv: 13.131.32.0, lease-time: 31536000]
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 Successful ARP Flush on interface [4] {269323C2-CA34-4A09-A10B-3C465C1A9832}
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1692703846,ASSIGN_IP,,13.131.32.2,,,,
    2023-08-22 14:30:46 IPv4 MTU set to 1500 on interface 4 using service
    2023-08-22 14:30:51 TEST ROUTES: 2/2 succeeded len=2 ret=1 a=0 u/d=up
    2023-08-22 14:30:51 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1692703851,ADD_ROUTES,,,,,,
    2023-08-22 14:30:51 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 13.131.31.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 13.131.32.1
    2023-08-22 14:30:51 Route addition via service succeeded
    2023-08-22 14:30:51 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 13.131.30.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 13.131.32.1
    2023-08-22 14:30:51 Route addition via service succeeded
    2023-08-22 14:30:51 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
    2023-08-22 14:30:51 Initialization Sequence Completed
    2023-08-22 14:30:51 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1692703851,CONNECTED,SUCCESS,13.131.32.2,XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX,12345,,
    2023-08-22 14:36:00 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe DELETE 13.131.31.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 13.131.32.1
    2023-08-22 14:36:00 Route deletion via service succeeded
    2023-08-22 14:36:00 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe DELETE 13.131.30.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 13.131.32.1
    2023-08-22 14:36:00 Route deletion via service succeeded
    2023-08-22 14:36:00 Closing TUN/TAP interface
    2023-08-22 14:36:00 TAP: DHCP address released
    2023-08-22 14:36:00 SIGTERM[hard,] received, process exiting
    2023-08-22 14:36:00 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1692704160,EXITING,SIGTERM,,,,,
    2023-08-22 14:46:30 DEPRECATED OPTION: --cipher set to 'AES-256-CBC' but missing in --data-ciphers (AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM). Future OpenVPN version will ignore --cipher for cipher negotiations. Add 'AES-256-CBC' to --data-ciphers or change --cipher 'AES-256-CBC' to --data-ciphers-fallback 'AES-256-CBC' to silence this warning.
    2023-08-22 14:46:30 OpenVPN 2.5.5 Windows-MSVC [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [PKCS11] [AEAD] built on Dec 15 2021
    2023-08-22 14:46:30 Windows version 10.0 (Windows 10 or greater) 64bit
    2023-08-22 14:46:30 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021, LZO 2.10
    2023-08-22 14:46:30 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
    2023-08-22 14:46:30 Need hold release from management interface, waiting...
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'log all on'
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'echo all on'
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'bytecount 5'
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold off'
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:12345
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 UDP link local: (not bound)
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:12345
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1692704791,WAIT,,,,,,
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1692704791,AUTH,,,,,,
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:12345, sid=162ab77b 83006b9d
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 VERIFY OK: depth=1, CN=Easy-RSA CA
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 VERIFY KU OK
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 Validating certificate extended key usage
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 ++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 VERIFY EKU OK
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=server
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 WARNING: 'link-mtu' is used inconsistently, local='link-mtu 1601', remote='link-mtu 1585'
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 WARNING: 'keysize' is used inconsistently, local='keysize 256', remote='keysize 128'
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 Control Channel: TLSv1.3, cipher TLSv1.3 TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, peer certificate: 2048 bit RSA, signature: RSA-SHA256
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 [server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:12345
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4,route 13.131.31.0 255.255.255.0 13.131.32.1,route 13.131.30.0 255.255.255.0 13.131.32.1,client-to-client,route-gateway 13.131.32.1,topology subnet,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 13.131.32.2 255.255.255.0,peer-id 0,cipher AES-256-GCM'
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 Options error: option 'client-to-client' cannot be used in this context ([PUSH-OPTIONS])
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 OPTIONS IMPORT: peer-id set
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 OPTIONS IMPORT: adjusting link_mtu to 1624
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 OPTIONS IMPORT: data channel crypto options modified
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 Data Channel: using negotiated cipher 'AES-256-GCM'
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 Outgoing Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 Incoming Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 interactive service msg_channel=880
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 open_tun
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 tap-windows6 device [Yerel Ağ Bağlantısı] opened
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 TAP-Windows Driver Version 9.24 
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 Set TAP-Windows TUN subnet mode network/local/netmask = 13.131.32.0/13.131.32.2/255.255.255.0 [SUCCEEDED]
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 Notified TAP-Windows driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of 13.131.32.2/255.255.255.0 on interface {269323C2-CA34-4A09-A10B-3C465C1A9832} [DHCP-serv: 13.131.32.0, lease-time: 31536000]
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 Successful ARP Flush on interface [4] {269323C2-CA34-4A09-A10B-3C465C1A9832}
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1692704791,ASSIGN_IP,,13.131.32.2,,,,
    2023-08-22 14:46:31 IPv4 MTU set to 1500 on interface 4 using service
    2023-08-22 14:46:36 TEST ROUTES: 2/2 succeeded len=2 ret=1 a=0 u/d=up
    2023-08-22 14:46:36 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1692704796,ADD_ROUTES,,,,,,
    2023-08-22 14:46:36 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 13.131.31.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 13.131.32.1
    2023-08-22 14:46:36 Route addition via service succeeded
    2023-08-22 14:46:36 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 13.131.30.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 13.131.32.1
    2023-08-22 14:46:36 Route addition via service succeeded
    2023-08-22 14:46:36 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
    2023-08-22 14:46:36 Initialization Sequence Completed
    2023-08-22 14:46:36 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1692704796,CONNECTED,SUCCESS,13.131.32.2,XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX,12345,,
```

UPDATE:

***route print(connected):***

```
            Interface List
      5...0a 00 27 00 00 05 ......VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
     36...........................Wintun Userspace Tunnel
      4...00 ff 26 93 23 c2 ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
     38...1c bf c0 7d 57 4f ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
     14...9e bf c0 7d 57 4f ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
     16...1c bf c0 7d 57 4f ......Realtek 8822CE Wireless LAN 802.11ac PCI-E NIC
     13...1c bf c0 7d 57 50 ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network) #19
      1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
    ===========================================================================
    
    IPv4 Route Table
    ===========================================================================
    Active Routes:
    Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
              0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.34.44.1     10.34.45.210     41
           10.34.44.0    255.255.254.0         On-link      10.34.45.210    296
         10.34.45.210  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.34.45.210    296
         10.34.45.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.34.45.210    296
          13.131.30.0    255.255.255.0      13.131.32.1      13.131.32.2    281
          13.131.31.0    255.255.255.0      13.131.32.1      13.131.32.2    281
          13.131.32.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       13.131.32.2    281
          13.131.32.2  255.255.255.255         On-link       13.131.32.2    281
        13.131.32.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       13.131.32.2    281
            127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
            127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
         192.168.56.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.56.1    261
         192.168.56.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    261
       192.168.56.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    261
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.56.1    261
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       13.131.32.2    281
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      10.34.45.210    296
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    261
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       13.131.32.2    281
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.34.45.210    296
    ===========================================================================
    Persistent Routes:
      None
    
    IPv6 Route Table
    ===========================================================================
    Active Routes:
     If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
      1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
      5    281 fe80::/64                On-link
      4    281 fe80::/64                On-link
     16    296 fe80::/64                On-link
      5    281 fe80::3e20:acc1:fa57:4695/128
                                        On-link
     16    296 fe80::f63b:b12d:824:66af/128
                                        On-link
      4    281 fe80::fa92:1f5:c284:7299/128
                                        On-link
      1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
      5    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
      4    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
     16    296 ff00::/8                 On-link
    ===========================================================================
    Persistent Routes:
      None
```

***route print(not connected):***

```
            Interface List
      5...0a 00 27 00 00 05 ......VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
     36...........................Wintun Userspace Tunnel
      4...00 ff 26 93 23 c2 ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
     38...1c bf c0 7d 57 4f ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
     14...9e bf c0 7d 57 4f ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
     16...1c bf c0 7d 57 4f ......Realtek 8822CE Wireless LAN 802.11ac PCI-E NIC
     13...1c bf c0 7d 57 50 ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network) #19
      1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
    ===========================================================================
    
    IPv4 Route Table
    ===========================================================================
    Active Routes:
    Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
              0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.34.44.1     10.34.45.210     41
           10.34.44.0    255.255.254.0         On-link      10.34.45.210    296
         10.34.45.210  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.34.45.210    296
         10.34.45.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.34.45.210    296
            127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
            127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
         192.168.56.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.56.1    261
         192.168.56.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    261
       192.168.56.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    261
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.56.1    261
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      10.34.45.210    296
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    261
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.34.45.210    296
    ===========================================================================
    Persistent Routes:
      None
    
    IPv6 Route Table
    ===========================================================================
    Active Routes:
     If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
      1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
      5    281 fe80::/64                On-link
     16    296 fe80::/64                On-link
      5    281 fe80::3e20:acc1:fa57:4695/128
                                        On-link
     16    296 fe80::f63b:b12d:824:66af/128
                                        On-link
      1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
      5    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
     16    296 ff00::/8                 On-link
    ===========================================================================
    Persistent Routes:
      None
```

Comment: Yuor "IP routing" looks like Linux but your "Client Log" seems to be from a MS-Windows host. Are you using MS-Windows as the client for openvpn? The other way around? If the former, what are the routing tables from the client connected and not connected?

Comment: Yes, openvpn runs on ubuntu server and client is windows 10. I have added the client's routing table.

Comment: check this answer : https://serverfault.com/questions/736274/openvpn-client-to-client

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. @D'Arcy Nader  i think it's probably about routing table.

Comment: Do you have any idea @symcbean

Comment: It looks you are trying to send routing from the client to the server (`push "route...`) this should just be `route....`